# How to add user HTTP Headers in CXF response?

Tags: web-services, cxf

For some reason there is no 'Content-Length' HTTP headers in CXF response.
I've decided to implement interceptor that does it, but unfortunately there is no added header in sent data (intercepted using Wireshark). I can set breakpoint and i can see interceptor is invoked. What's wrong?

```
/**
 * Adds Content-Length header for the outcoming messages
 */
public class AddContentLengthInterceptor extends AbstractLoggingInterceptor {

    private static final String CONTENT_LENGTH_ADDED = AddContentLengthInterceptor.class.getName() + ".log-setup";

    public AddContentLengthInterceptor(String phase) {
        super(phase);
        addBefore(StaxOutInterceptor.class.getName());
    }
    public AddContentLengthInterceptor() {
        this(Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL); // before streaming
    }

    @Override
    protected Logger getLogger() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        final OutputStream os = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
        final Writer iowriter = message.getContent(Writer.class);
        if (os == null && iowriter == null) {
            return;
        }

        // ignore double processing of the message
        boolean hasAddedHeader = message.containsKey(CONTENT_LENGTH_ADDED);
        if (!hasAddedHeader) {
            message.put(CONTENT_LENGTH_ADDED, Boolean.TRUE);
            if (os != null) {
                // Write the output while caching it for adding header later
                final CacheAndWriteOutputStream newOut = new CacheAndWriteOutputStream(os);
                message.setContent(OutputStream.class, newOut);
                newOut.registerCallback(new LoggingCallback(message, os));
            }
        }
    }

    class LoggingCallback implements CachedOutputStreamCallback {

        private final Message message;
        private final OutputStream origStream;

        public LoggingCallback(final Message msg, final OutputStream os) {
            this.message = msg;
            this.origStream = os;
        }

        public void onFlush(CachedOutputStream cos) {

        }

        public void onClose(CachedOutputStream cos) {
            long contentLength = cos.size();

            Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
            if (headers == null)
                headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            headers.put("Content-Length", Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(contentLength)));
            message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);

            try {
                // empty out the cache
                cos.lockOutputStream();
                cos.resetOut(null, false);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //ignore
            }
            message.setContent(OutputStream.class, origStream);
        }
    }
}
```

This is now server-side endpoints are created:

```
    mediaService = new MediaService(ip, rtspPort, streamUri);
    ProviderImpl provider = new ProviderImpl();
    mediaEndpoint = (EndpointImpl) provider.createEndpoint(null, mediaService);
    String mediaServiceURL = MessageFormat.format("http://{0}:{1}/onvif/media_service", ip, String.valueOf(port));
    mediaEndpoint.publish(mediaServiceURL);

    // add "Content-Length" header
    mediaEndpoint.getServer().getEndpoint().getOutInterceptors().add(contentLengthInterceptor);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Transfer-Encoding as chunked. Which results in no content-length header since it is defined that way in [RFC](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.4.4).

> Messages MUST NOT include both a Content-Length header field and a
>   non-identity transfer-coding. If the message does include a
>   non-identity transfer-coding, the Content-Length MUST be ignored.

I am not exactly sure but, either cxf removes your header since it is not allowed or it sets but sub layers remove it. As far as I know cxf uses HttpUrlConnection to transport your message. And that layer sets Content-length header on normal cases. But since you are using chunked transfer, that layer may override it.

In order to fix it you must change your Transfer-Encoding. And since CXF's itself sets content-length header you are no longer need to write your Interceptor.

By the way, if you use a custom header, you will realise that your interceptor works like a charm.

Comment: It seems you're right! How can i turn off chunking at server-side programmatically (no spring, no xmls)? I need to have "Content-Length" in headers as some ancient webservice client needs it.